# Visual Studio 2013 for creating an AWS Lambda function in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

[image: a screenshot to make things more clear]Can I create a Lambda function in c# in the visual studio 2013. I wil have to install the .net core framework for the same, but once I do that will I be able to do the same in C# ? right now in the current version I dont have any option for AWS Lambda under the c# language . It can only be written in in node.js.
Can this be done with VS13 or I need VS15 for the same ?

Answer (score 0):

Install the AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio 2013-2015.

Comment: In that case I would suggest using .NET Core instead. Core generally brings improvements in performance and architecture anyway.

Comment: are you sure that once I install the .net core I will be able to make a lambda function in c# language . because till now as you can see it is only availabe in one language that is node.js .

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/lambda-index.html

"To install the Toolkit for Visual Studio you must have either Visual Studio 2017 or Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and .NET Core for Windows installed. "

Comment: that is not true, there is a toolkit available for visual studio 2013 as well and i have it installed on my system.